# requestImageDataForAsset returns nil image data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've been stuck with this for couple of days. I've bee trying to get the image within the call back but I always get `nil`. These the options which I used:

```
 let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.deliveryMode = .HighQualityFormat
            options.resizeMode = .None
```

I also tried with options set to `nil` without any luck. This is the data I got in the info value passed to the block.

```
[PHImageResultIsInCloudKey: 0, 
 PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey: 9999, 
 PHImageFileURLKey: file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0052.JPG, 
 PHImageResultRequestIDKey: 84, 
 PHImageResultIsDegradedKey: 0, 
 PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey: 9999,  
 PHImageResultIsPlaceholderKey: 0, 
 PHImageFileSandboxExtensionTokenKey: 
  64b47b046511a340c57aa1e3e6e07994c1a13853;00000000;00000000;0000001a;com.apple.app-sandbox.read;;00000000;00000000;0000000000000000;/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0051.JPG]
```

I also tried using `requestImageForAsset` and I got the same result. I thought by using `requestImageDataForAsset` I'll get more control on the data.

Also, I thought the file exists in the cloud, but it is not as `PHImageResultIsInCloudKey` value is set `0`; otherwise, I'd download it.

by the way, I am able to get a smaller version of the image with predefined size of `200x200` inside another view; however, when I try to get the larger version of it, I get nil. I know that the image exists on the phone with higher res (I can see it in the Photos app)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and tried setting the networkAccessAllowed option on the PHImageRequestOptions object to YES - that seemed to fix it.  For me the issue was definitely that the images were in the cloud as images on the camera roll worked fine but those in the cloud did not.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. I think there is a bug in PHImageRequestOptions class , so we pass nil in the bellow code ,it's helpful for me.

```
            dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
            [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                assetModel.size = imageData.length;
                NSString *filename = [asset valueForKey:@"filename"];
                assetModel.fileName = filename;
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
            }];
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```